# Python output mistakes caused by csv, txt, and xls switching date formats (MM/DD/YYYY and M/D/YY)

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, xlwt

I wrote a python script that takes a csv which has dates in an M/D/YYYY format, then matches them with dates in an xlwt generated .xls file. I was wondering why only some dates are matched and then I noticed that the only dates that were matched were strings that were 10 characters long (11/14/2011) and dates that were not 10 characters long (1/14/2011 or 1/7/2012) were not matched. How do I get the csv file to save the dates in 10 character long strings? Or should I convert the csv file into a txt file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`csv` doesn't know *anything* about dates; it just reads text. You are comparing strings with other strings, and `'1/7/2012'` and `'01/07/2012'` are different strings altogether.

You'd need to parse the dates into something that *can* be compared, when reading. Use the `datetime.datetime.strptime()` function for that:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(datecolumn, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
```

The `strptime()` format above would turn both `1/7/2012` and `01/07/2012` into a `datetime.date(2012, 1, 7)`, and two copies of that `date()` instance would compare as equal.